# METHODS IN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

can any one define methods on javascript, little bit in easy way as im new to this language ???

Comment: "Methods" are object properties which are functions. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Have you tried doing any research at all before posting this question?

Comment: Next time, take 5s to type "what is method in javascript" in your friend Google and you'll find plenty of interesting stuff, like : https://www.utexas.edu/learn/javascript/objects.html, http://sharkysoft.com/archive/1997/jsa/content/039.html or even SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: ask google before asking to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this using inline object

```
var object = {
   method: function() {
       console.log('this is method');
   }
};

object.method();
```

using contructor:

```
function Foo() {
    this.method = function() {
        console.log('this is method');
    };
}
var object = new Foo();
object.method();
```

using prototype:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log('this is method');
};
var object = new Foo();
object.method();
```